# Calculate Range for Diagnostic report

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have this JSON

```json
{
  "components": [
    "component1",
    "component2",
    "component3"
  ],
  "validFrom": "someDate"
}
```

I would like to calculate the [`Range`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Range) for VSCode so that I can report [`Diagnostics`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Diagnostic) in my extension.

How can I calculate the Range, i.e. for `"component1"`? Some utility function should return something like `(startLine: 3, startCharacter: 5,  endLine: 3, endCharacter: 5 + component1.length)`.

Comment: Simple solution would probably be to just split content by (\n) --> I will get then how many rows are in the JSON. And then I can check each line if it contains a specific string...

Answer (score 1):

With the [jsonc-parser](https://github.com/microsoft/node-jsonc-parser), which is also used by VS Code itself to parse JSON content btw., you can parse the document and get the range of an element.

This sample demonstrates how to get the range of `"component1"`:

```js
import { findNodeAtLocation, parseTree } from "jsonc-parser";
...
//Parse JSON of a TextDocument
const rootNode = parseTree(textDocument.getText());
// Find first element of the "components" array
const firstComponent = findNodeAtLocation(rootNode, ["components", 0]);
const start = textDocument.positionAt(firstComponent.offset);
const end = textDocument.positionAt(firstComponent.offset + firstComponent.length)
const range = new Range(start, end);
```

(Please note: I skipped any check for `undefined`)

Comment: Yeah, I needed exactly this one :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning information is usually provided by a parser. It determines the individual tokens in the input and their location. This can then be used to generate Monaco ranges for various purposes (code completion, error diagnostics, edit actions etc.).